# Easiest way to burn single audio file to CD with track points in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, burning, compact-disc

Do I really need to split the single file into multiple files first? Shouldn't there be a one-step utility that lets you burn a CD and define track points at the same time?

Comment: Add your operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a [cue sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_%28computing%29) and burn the audio CD with software that supports cue sheets (e.g. **[Burrrn](http://www.burrrn.net/?page_id=4)**)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what operating system you use, yes and no. I'm sure there's a Linux application that will do this, but on Windows and Mac I don't know of any.

You would have to split the file down before you burn it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done impromptu track cuts with Nero 6 and 7 using Windows XP.
This will produce a noraml CD that will play in a normal CD player.
You can user Nero in Normal mode or Express Mode. Here is a copy of the [manual](http://ftp6.nero.com/user_guides/backitup-and-burn/express/NeroExpress_Eng.pdf). [More info](http://club.myce.com/f57/howto-create-audiocd-mix-using-nero-48411/).

1. Open nero and start a new `Audio CD`
2. Add your track(s) to the list of Tracks to burn
3. Click on the Track then click the `Properties` button
4. In the next window, click the table named `Indexes, Limits, Split`
5. Click in the Timeline where you want to break the tracks.
6. Click the `Split` button.
7. Repeate for each of times to start the next track.